# String can't be converted to a double

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, double

I have a strange problem. I start by showing the error that I get in a sortLIST function, - which seems strange. The problem occurs for the string "i" as seen in the debug error which is separated by ",".
The first argument is 0.48 which is a double. Anyway the error says:

**Input string was not in a correct format**

I have also tried by remove the CultureInfo("en-Us") line with no success:

[image]

Now I have tried to simulate the above and executing this code in a button control and here it DO work and gives no error:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    String i = "0.48,trx/btc,coss,hitbtc2,0.0000062000 / 0.0000066000,0.0000061502 / 0.0000061701,,0.48%";
    double test = double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0]);

    MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
}
```

What can cause this error? I have put the below line in ALL functions in the application to be on the safe side:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: The input string in question is the argument passed to `Double.Parse`, which is covered up by the watch window for i. What is passed to `Double.Parse`?

Comment: The string: 0.48 is passed to Double.Parse which should be able to Convert to a double?

Comment: If you put in the literal `"0.48"` do you get the error?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I have only tried the example I have in the button1_Click which should simulate it exactly? (which strangely do work as expected)

Comment: I tried to put in the literal "0.48" but that did not help.

Answer (score 4):

The image you uploaded shows you are actually running multiple threads, but the culture is only being set for the current thread.

To overcome this you can assign the desired culture to a variable and use it inside `Task.Factory.StartNew`.  You can do something like this:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // use culture here
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

    // your actual code here
    String i = "0.48,trx/btc,coss,hitbtc2,0.0000062000 / 0.0000066000,0.0000061502 / 0.0000061701,,0.48%";
    double test = double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0]);
});
```

As @madreflection pointed out you can just pass the desired culture to `double.Parse()` method:

```
// put this at the top of your file
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

// use this inside Task.Factory.StartNew
double test = double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0], culture);
```

Or even use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` inside `Task.Factory` (thanks @Olivier):

```
double test = double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Alternatively, pass an en-US CultureInfo instance to `double.Parse` in the [second parameter](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Double.Parse(String,IFormatProvider)).

Comment: That was a beatiful thing. Then I see, the culture was only set for one thread. I was not thinking it was needed  more than in the function itself. But is true then as it is multiple threads involved there. Many thanks, I was scratching my head there :)

Comment: You also simply use the invariant culture: `double test = Double.Parse("0.48", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Yes I see that is a good approach too. I learned something nice today!!!